# Create a minidump of an application on Windows Mobile / Pocket PC 2003

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, pocketpc, minidump, memory-dump

How do I create a minidump of a user-mode application (containing all the mapped memory for said usermode application) on the Windows Mobile or Pocket PC 2003 platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Itsutils offers a memory dump tool (see itsme on xda-developers.com). But you need to know the start address.what is the intention for making this dump?

Comment: The intention is to dump what's in virtual memory for a single process in order to search for a saved (but forgotten) password.  I was hoping to avoid having to dump the entirety of physical memory.

Comment: You do not need to dump the whole memory, you only need to dump the slot memory where the process is located. If the app is a .net one you can use an IDL viewer to look for the password. See for example: http://sebug.net/paper/Meeting-Documents/Xcon-2005/Xcon2005_Hacking_Windows_CE.pdf

Comment: I caved in and gave this method a try.  I got back `ERROR: Source/host file does not exist 'C:\Win32\itsutils\enablerapi.exe'` from trying to run pmemdump.exe and pmemmap.exe.  Where does enablerapi.exe come from?

Comment: I never had issues with the itsutils. Supporting that is done at different place.

Comment: @user314104 I have the same question, I cannot find "enablerapi.exe". Did you ever find it?

Comment: enabler.api is not part of itsutils: see https://itsme.home.xs4all.nl/projects/xda/tools.html